# How to reset Battery chart

Tags: battery, battery-history

I have an Android tablet (wifi only; no cell service). Sometimes, I want to reset the chart it shows in the battery menu, so that it only shows the last few min instead of the last who knows how many hours.  I know it can be done because I did it once before, though I wasn't paying attention to how it happened that time. Thus, I no longer remember what I did that time. So how can I do it again?

Answer (score 0):

By clearing that Chart you mean that you have to reset the **"batterystats.bin"** file in your system. For that few apps are available on the Playstore but unfortunately you need to **ROOT** your device since those are system files.
One such app is [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vitula.batterycalibration)

Hope that helps!

Comment: what about the opposite?  after 5 days i am at risk of the battery chart resetting by itself as soon as i start charging, even if I don't hit 90%.  i was able to get as high as 8 days but recently i can't even get to 6 days.